# Using insertion sort to sort only part of array

Tags: java, quicksort

I'm writing a quicksort program. Part of the quicksort involves using insertionsort, but it only sorts a certain range of elements, since quicksort handles the rest. I'm trying to emulate a method provided by my textbook that uses

```
   public static void insertionSort(int a[], int left, int right)
```

But I am struggling to figure out how left and right are used. Here is the insertionsort code without using the parameters left and right:

```
public static void insertionSort(int a[], int left, int right) {
    int j;
    for (int p = 1; p < a.length; p++) {
        int tmp = a[p];
        for(j = p; j > 0 && tmp < a[j - 1]; j--) {
            a[j] = a[j-1];
        }
        a[j] = tmp;
    }
}
```

If I were to add the left and right parameters to help sort only part of the array, where would they apply?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use left and right in the for loop declaration:

```
public static void insertionSort(int a[], int left, int right) {
    int j;
    for (int p = left; p < right; p++) {
        int tmp = a[p];
        for(j = p; j > 0 && tmp < a[j - 1]; j--) {
            a[j] = a[j-1];
        }
        a[j] = tmp;
    }
}
```

example input:  insertionSort({3, 2, 6, 5, 8, 3, 6, 7, 0}, 2, 6)

example output: {3, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 6, 7, 0}

edit:

In the above example, left is inclusive and right is exclusive. If you want to include the right index, change p < right to p<= right. Keep in mind when calling the method that indexing starts at 0.

Comment: I would explain whether left and right are inclusive or exclusive, and explain whether left and right are zero based or one based indices.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried this, and there was one little anomaly that I encountered and it didn't quite sort right. Instead of p < right, I used p < right + 1, and it seemed to sort well.

Comment: @Rainbolt that's good to clarify. John yep, that's what rainbolt was asking me to clarify. Glad you figured it out.